# Room Dao Left Outer Join sets parentId to 0 when join does not find children

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

I have a standard outer join in Room Dao which strangely ends up setting parent `joinId` (bakeId) to 0 whenever join didn't find any child rows.
Is this a room bug or a normal behavior? Any idea how to get proper `joinId` (bakeId), without changing the schema?

```
@Query(
    "SELECT * FROM ${Bake.tableName} " +
        "left outer JOIN ${Ingredient.tableName} ON ${Bake.tableName}.${Bake.Columns.bakeId} " +
        "= ${Ingredient.tableName}.${Ingredient.Columns.bakeId}" +
        " ORDER BY ${Bake.Columns.bakeId} DESC , ${Bake.Columns.startTime} DESC"
)
fun getBakesFlow(): Flow<Map<Bake, List<Ingredient>>>
```

The problem I think is that both parent and child tables have the join column named exactly the same

Comment: This can't be normal behavior. Since you also use ORDER BY, are all these rows with id=0 placed at the bottom of the resultset?

Comment: No it's sorted properly

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a bug with version `"2.4.3"`, I updated room to `"2.5.0-beta02"` and it's no longer happening.